# not able to access localhost:3000 outside vmware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i am running webrick default ROR server inside vmware in ubuntu. i have host window as Window 10.but in window 10 browser i am not able to access the 0.0.0.0:3000 . i have ruby on rails code, how can i host in my own machine server?
in window10 browser i get error like-
[error][1]

[VMware and real host ip snapshot][2]

puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count


port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }


environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }


plugin :tmp_restart


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N65uJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/At2Rz.png
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325663/access-webrick-rails-from-another-computer-on-local-network
Otherwise look into `ngrok`

Comment: I think you are looking for 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: What kind of networking are you using for your vmware client?  If you are using bridged networking then what is the IP address of the client?

Comment: @BenTrewern i have added snapshot of ip distribution in question.i am using bridged network and vmware workstation 15. how can i access outside workstation? on running rails server.

Comment: I meant check the ip address from inside your vmware client!  I'm currently using Vmware Fusion on a Mac so may be different, but using bridged networking is like having a separate host on your network.  You should be able to access your rails app at http://[client-ip]:3000